# Unknown error when login with Lock +Social + Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook, single-sign-on, auth0

I am trying to get authentication implemented in my iOS (Swift) app using Auth0 as I want to add social integration (Facebook, Google and Instagram). I followed all of the steps on their [starter guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift/00-getting-started). I setup the connections on my Auth0 console, and tested them (click the try button once setup).

However, once a user taps on Login with Facebook/Google/instagram, onError is called and this is the localized description: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Lock.OAuth2AuthenticatableError error 1.)

Furthermore, this error message is briefly displayed after login callback:

[image]

I have been working on this for the past few days with no luck :( I also could not find that error code anywhere...

```
Lock
  .classic()
  .onError(callback: { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  })
  .onAuth { credentials in
    // Do something with credentials e.g.: save them.
    print(credentials)
    // Lock will not save these objects for you.
    // Lock will dismiss itself automatically by default.
  }
  .present(from: self)
```